# Filter Multi-Channel Funnels (MFC) interactionType on campaignPath through Google Analytics API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm doing a MFC query through Google Analytics python API like:

```
query = service.data().mcf().get(
    ids = "ga:79961457",
    start_date = day,
    end_date = day,
    metrics = metric,
    dimensions = "mcf:conversionDate,mcf:campaignPath",
    sort = None,
    filters = "mcf:campaignPath=@RTG,mcf:conversionType==Transaction",
    max_results = 1000000000
).execute()
```

This yields a list with rows similar to this:

> {u'primitiveValue': u'20160701'},
>
> {u'conversionPathValue':
>
> [{u'nodeValue': u'{{soporte}}',  u'interactionType': u'CLICK'},
>
> {u'nodeValue': u'RTG', 
>   u'interactionType': u'IMPRESSION'},
>
> {u'nodeValue': u'CAMP', 
>   u'interactionType': u'CLICK'}],
>
> {u'primitiveValue': u'1'},FBRTG

Now, the filter I applied is

> mcf:campaignPath=@RTG

And it filters throught all "nodeValue".

The thing is that I want to get only the rows that contains

> {u'nodeValue': u'RTG', 
>   u'interactionType': u'CLICK'},

(for example)

So, the problem is: how can i apply a filter to the interactionType, not only the campaignPath?

Comment: If *"MFC"* and *"MCF"* are the same to you, you need to work on your diligence.

Comment: Sorry, I have been almost all day with this problem and my head is exploding.