# How to request multi-funnel conversions?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For a while a requested Aanlytics reports by building service with googleapiclient in Python.

```
service = build('analytics', 'v4', http = http, discoveryServiceUrl = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'))
```

Now I need reports about multi-funnel conversions mfc parameters like: 'expression': 'mcf:totalConversions' ,'name': 'mcf:campaignPath'

But when i send request - I get 400 error that dimensions/metrics are unknown.
I cannot find in documentation information which can help me - I don't understand why I can not get this data from this service.

Comment: this maybe? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution to this? I am on the same journey to get the Google API python client working with the MCF API.

I've only been able to get the MCF API working with Analytics API v3. I'm not sure if that is the only supported version, or if I need to do something different for v4. There is very little documentation that I've found. I was able to connect to the API like this:

```
service = build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

The discoveryServiceUrl parameter shouldn't be necessary. I tried it and it should work if you replace *analyticsreporting* (API v4) with *analytics* (API v3).

```
service = build('analytics', 'v3', credentials=credentials, discoveryServiceUrl = ('https://analytics.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'))
```

I've used these other Stack Overflow topics to get data responses from MCF. It's very different from the typical Analytics API.

- [First Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658055/filter-multi-channel-funnels-mfc-interactiontype-on-campaignpath-through-googl)
- [Second Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129766/ga-multi-channel-funnel-analytics-with-python-and-filters-in-the-mcf-get-method)